# How to download a file from a site, process it, then insert it into an Azure SQL database table?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I need to download the file named "StatesCONUS.Heating.txt" from:

ftp://ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/htdocs/degree_days/weighted/daily_data/2020/

Then, I need to parse the data and insert it into a table in an Azure SQL Database.

This would have to be done once a day.

I am a Noob in azure, so what would be the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways.

1-Write an Azure Function with time trigger, downloads the file in memory (assuming it's not that big) and insert the rows into sql database

2-Use Azure Logic Apps with Time Trigger, use ftp connector to download the file, then use sql database connector to insert the rows into the sql database

3-Use Azure Functions / Logic App, save the file into storage account. Trigger another function which will process it or use Azure Data Factory to process and insert into Sql Database.

Useful resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-recurrence

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sftp

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/sql/